# Error when applying function by factor in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe consisting of four columns. The third is a factor variable, with levels A and B, and the fourth variable is numeric. I want to flip the sign of the numeric variable if the corresponding factorlevel is B. So, given a row x of my dataframe, I want to do this:

```
negate <- function(x) { 
  if(x[3] == B) {
    x[4] <- -x[4]
  }
}
```

However, when I try

```
apply(dataframe,1,negate)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in -x[4] : invalid argument to unary operator
```

How do I do what I want to do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be vectorized:

```
logicalVector <- x[3]=="B"
negativeVector <- c(1,-1)[logicalVector+1]
x[4] <- x[4}*negativeVector
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `apply` function here (just use `ifelse`) :

```
mydata$col4<-with(mydata,ifelse(col3=="B",-col4,col4))
```

Test using iris data from R:

```
mydata<-iris
mydata$Petal.Length<-with(mydata,ifelse(Species=="setosa",-Petal.Length,Petal.Length))
> mydata
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5         -1.4         0.2     setosa
2            4.9         3.0         -1.4         0.2     setosa
3            4.7         3.2         -1.3         0.2     setosa
4            4.6         3.1         -1.5         0.2     setosa
```

Comment: Thank you! Since Ari was first, I'm giving him the checkmark. But your answer is very helpful as well! Do you have any idea why my attempt failed?

Comment: replace `ifelse` with `if` since the former does the vectorized operation and as I said you don't need `apply`